# How to set Youtube iframe embed to HD (2022 edition)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube, embed

I've got a full page Youtube video embed on a page and recently I've noticed it defaults to low quality. I saw this is a common problem that had different solutions at different points in time so I was wondering if anyone has any new tips?

I've tried setting the width and height of the iframe to 1920x1080 and adding `&vq=hd1080` or `&vq=hd1080p` to the source url but none of these seemed to work.

Comment: You need to adjust your account setting for that.  Good tutorial here https://www.embedplus.com/force-high-definition-hd-youtube-embed.aspx

Comment: but most the users don't even know they can set de quality, so it goes automatically and when you need a 1080 video it will get quite bad because youtube sets to low quality always, no matter how fast is your connection. Eg: a 100Mbps will get 480px, I tested. It sucks but I also didn't find a way to set high quality as default.